# How to remove message custom flag?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I give each message in client's inbox a default custom tag, let's say "important"

```
Flags flag = new Flags("important");
message.setFlags(flag,true);
```

Isn't there anyway to remove this tag, I don't need it to anymore, and it shouldn't be persisted in the database anymore... It's not about setting it false instead of true, i just want to remove it permanently!

Comment: No, i am not talking about deleting a message and then deleting orphans & garbage collection. I want to remove a tag from message without deleting it, that is the difference.

Comment: Flags either exist on the message or they don't.  Setting the flag to true causes it to exist on the message. Setting it to false causes it to be removed from the message.  If that's not working, please show the debug output.  If that's not what you're trying to do, please explain again.

Comment: This is correct when you are talking about flags which are instance variables of message class. But when we are talking about custom flags, it seems different, i can add many flags to one message in an independent table mapped by the composite primary key of the message as a foreign key. The question is how to delete these tags and remove them !?

Comment: I told you how to remove them from the client side.  If they're not being removed on the server side, that's a bug in the server.  And, as I said, if they're correctly being removed from all messages and are just left around in some table on the server side, that's a "garbage collection" problem on the server.

Comment: do you mean that removing flags is the same regardless their type ? The point where i am conflicted at is removing custom tags, not message flags(isSeen, isDeleted)... May be my English language is not clear enough to explain my question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like we can remove message flags in this code, as the javamail API source code comments says. I tried it and it works.

```
  Flags flag = new Flags("IMPORTANT");
  message.setFlags(flag,false);
```